# Access from django admin list_display, a value from a One-To-One table

Tags: django, django-admin, django-1.5

Given a one-to-one extension a model, such as the Django User model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
     user        = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', unique=True)
     avatar      = models.ImageField(_('Avatar'))
     foo         = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="xxx")
```

How can I display that in the admin?

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('email', 'profile__foo' <--NOT WORKING )
```

A near match question is [Django Admin: How to display value of fields with list_display from two models which are in oneToOne relation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328714/django-admin-how-to-display-value-of-fields-with-list-display-from-two-models-w)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The general method would be:

```
class UseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('email', 'profile_foo')
    def profile_foo(self, x):
        return x.profile.foo
    profile_foo.short_description = 'foo'
```

x here is the object of the model you are displaying

Comment: What if you wanted it to be list editable?