# django admin list_display SQL joindata

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

The pages made of existing php are being changed to python and Django.

Existing Query

```
Select
    l.lawyer_idx,
    l.lawyer_email,
    lp.lawyer_profile_path,
    lp.lawyer_profile_name,
    lc.lawyer_company_name,
    lc.lawyer_company_address,
    lc.lawyer_detail_address,
    l.lawyer_agent
from lawyer l
left join lawyer_profile lp on l.lawyer_idx = lp.lawyer_idx
left join lawyer_company lc on l.lawyer_idx = lc.lawyer_idx
order by l.register_date desc;
```

I made each table at models.py

```
    models.py

    class Lawyer(models.Model):
     lawyer_idx = models.AutoField('ID', primary_key=True)
      lawyer_email = models.CharField('E-mail', unique=True, max_length=200)
     lawyer_agent = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'lawyer'


    class LawyerProfile(models.Model):
     lawyer_idx = models.AutoField('ID', primary_key=True)
     lawyer_profile_path = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
   lawyer_profile_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
.................

    class LawyerCompany(models.Model):
     lawyer_idx = models.AutoField('ID', primary_key=True)
     lawyer_company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...............
```

We would like to place the following query into the 
list_display portion of Django Admin.py Is there any way to show the data that did join in sql?

```
    Admin.py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import Lawyer, LawyerCompany, LawyerProfile

    @admin.register(Lawyer)
    class LawyerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

       list_per_page = 100
       **list_display = ['lawyer_idx', 'lawyer_email', 
'lawyer_agent', 'lawyer_profile_path', 'lawyer_profile_name', 'lawyer_company_name']**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the query as a raw sql query, but that wouldnt make much use of Django's ORM then.

You are not explicitly defining any relationships on your models, so Django doesn't know about how your models relate.

If `lawyer_idx` references the lawyer you could change the field to a `OneToOneField`/`ForeignKey` (an `AutoField` is probably the wrong choice here anyways, as the values should correspond to those in the `Lawyer` model and not be auto-generated). Also have a look at the documentation for [one-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) and [many-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) relationships.

```
class LawyerProfile(models.Model):
     lawyer = models.OneToOneField(Lawyer, primary_key=True, 
         db_column="lawyer_idx", related_name="profile")
```

Django should perform the joins automatically when accessing the related data; on a `Lawyer` instance you can then access the profile via its `related_name` `.profile`. In the `list_display` option you can use the double underscore syntax to access related data:

```
list_display = ['lawyer_idx','lawyer_agent', 'profile__lawyer_profile_path']
list_select_related = ['profile']
```

If you add the [`list_select_related` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_select_related) Django will already join the specified table beforehand, so no additional queries are performed when accessing the related data.

Comment: thanks~!I got a problem.                                                                                                File "C:\workspace\bhsn\models.py", line 603, in LawyerProfile
    lawyer_idx = models.OneToOneField(Lawyer, primary_key=True, db_column='lawyer_idx', related_name='profile')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Comment: Yes you need to add an `on_delete=models.CASCADE` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: i try this!!!!!!model.py  class LawyerCompany(models.Model):
    lawyer_idx = models.OneToOneField(Lawyer, primary_key=True, db_column="lawyer_idx", related_name="profile", on_delete='models.CASCADE')
    lawyer_company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)   AND admin.py -> list_display = ('lawyer_idx', 'profile__lawyer_company_name',)   BUT!!!!!!!!!ERRORS:
<class 'bhsn.admin.LawyerAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[6]' refers to 'profile__lawyer_company_name', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'LawyerAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'bhsn.Lawyer'.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that this doesnt seem to work with the `OneToOneField`, but you can do it like in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652949/access-from-django-admin-list-display-a-value-from-a-one-to-one-table